# Flutter: Why is the feature_brick separation between page, view and body?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I recently started working with [mason](https://pub.dev/packages/mason) and hit upon the [feature_brick](https://brickhub.dev/bricks/feature_brick/0.5.1) which has saved me a lot of time, but there's something I quite don't understand about this feature structure.

The brick creates a feature folder with three main widgets: `FeaturePage` and `FeatureView` in `view/feature_page.dart`, and `FeatureBody` in `widgets/feature_body.dart`. I understand that `FeaturePage` is responsible of providing blocs with a `BlocProvider` widget, and `FeatureView` is where the UI is and where `BlocBuilder`s should be at. But what about `FeatureBody`?

To me it seems like `FeatureBody` is doing the job of `FeatureView`, leaving the latter class mostly useless. Am I missing something here?

As far as I know, this separation between page and view is mostly for testing purposes. Is the separation between view and body helping in any way to this?

---

[image: Feature folder structure]

*Feature folder structure*

[image: feature_page.dart content]

*`feature_page.dart` content*

[image: feature_body.dart content]

*`feature_body.dart` content*